# How to separate character and integer value from a list of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the below code to separate a character value from a list of strings.

Code:

```
 function orc_display_vios($scope, $resource, $http) {

             var Violation = $resource('{% url "api_dispatch_list" "v1" "violation" %}');
             $scope.pdbpidlist = [];
             Violation.get({record_id:{{ object.id }}, limit:1500}, function (data) {
                //console.log("dataob", data.objects);
                angular.forEach(data.objects, function(v, i) {
                        var vpid = {
                            pdb_pid: v.pdb_pid
                        };
                        $scope.pdbpidlist.push(vpid)
                        $scope.pdbpidchar = [];
                        $scope.finalpdb = [];
                        for (i = 0; i < $scope.pdbpidlist.length; i++) {
                                 $scope.pdbpidchar[i] = $scope.pdbpidlist[i].match(/\d+/g).join([]);
                                 console.log("vid", $scope.pdbpidchar);
                        }

                 });

                console.log("vid", $scope.pdbpidlist.length);
            })
}
```

$scope.pdbpidlist will have a list of values of string (eg., D1234555, T1266667,..). The number of values in the list depends on the value I get from the resource as done in my code. Now I want to separate the character value in the example string as ( D1234555 as 1234555) for all the strings in $scope.pdbpidlist. I'm trying to do this in this following part of the whole original code shared above.

```
 $scope.pdbpidchar = [];
                            $scope.finalpdb = [];
                            for (i = 0; i < $scope.pdbpidlist.length; i++) {
                                     $scope.pdbpidchar[i] = $scope.pdbpidlist[i].match(/\d+/g).join([]);
                                     console.log("vid", $scope.pdbpidchar);
                            }
```

I want the $scope.pdbpidchar to have a list without the character value in the strings (eg., as 1234555,..). When I try the above code, I'm getting the following error, $scope.pdbpidlist[i].match is not a function. I'm not able to figure out the reason why it is throwing this error. Any new ideas to convert would also be appreciated.

Comment: Try `$scope.pdbpidlist[i].pdb_pid.match(...` assuming `v.pdb_pid` is a string

Comment: @UsermujM Oh yes! It works. v.pdb_pid is a string as u presumed.